# Android Seekbar Thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have a seekbar and I need to apply **getTemperatureColor function** on my seekbar's thumb to get the color from linear gradient wherever the thumb is selected on seekbar, but I am not getting any idea about doing it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have a bit idea of like it will be something like this

seekbar.getThumb("I need help here on applying the getTemperatureColor()");

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SeekBar seekBar = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    final LinearGradient test = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, 200.f, 380.f, new int[] { 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000},
            null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    RoundRectShape roundRectShape = new RoundRectShape(new float []{30f,30f,30f,30f,30f,30f,30f,30f},null,null);
    shape = new ShapeDrawable(roundRectShape);
    shape.getPaint().setShader(test);

    seekBar.setProgressDrawable((Drawable) shape);
  
   }
    
private int getTemperatureColor(float temperature) {
        //Color range from 0 - 40 degC
        float clipped = Math.max(0f, Math.min(40f, temperature));

        float scaled = ((40f - clipped) / 40f) * 255f;
        int blue = Math.round(scaled);
        int red = 255 - blue;

        return Color.rgb(red, 0, blue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it of any help?

```
 seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(getTemperatureColor(30), PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
```

Comment: Mr. Ruben I have set the thumb already. I just need to apply the last function named as getTemperatureColor() to the thumb.

Comment: Yes exactly dear I need to change the color of the thumb based on temperature.